# left arrow operator in Julia

Tags: julia, operators

I have a vector

```
a = collect(1:4)
```

What is the meaning of `a <- a` in Julia [result - `false`]

As per the documentation <- is not an assignment operator in Julia.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a way to check it (so that in the future you will be able to solve similar problems more easily):

```
julia> dump(:(a <- a))
Expr
  head: Symbol call
  args: Array{Any}((3,))
    1: Symbol <
    2: Symbol a
    3: Expr
      head: Symbol call
      args: Array{Any}((2,))
        1: Symbol -
        2: Symbol a
```

So as you can see `a <- a` is the same as `a < (-a)` thus you are comparing, using the `<` operator the `a` vector with the `-a` vector.